# Xamarin.Forms - ListView can not load whole ViewCell

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

I am having an issue with loading ViewCell in ListView in Xamarin.Forms application.

ViewCell is displayed correctly but only half of it. I tried to scroll down but I couldn't. The ListView ends loading but the ViewCell is designed to continue.

Thank you for your answers !

Comment: What if you set ListView's "HasUnevenRows" to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on [ListView.HasUnevenRows Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview.hasunevenrows?view=xamarin-forms):

> To automatically size row height to fit content, the developer first
>   sets the HasUnevenRows property to true; and, second, either leaves
>   RowHeight at its default value of -1, or sets it to -1 if it has been
>   changed.
>
> [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview.hasunevenrows?view=xamarin-forms#remarks)

More details in [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance#row-heights).